# Add emoticons in tweet text updated using tweepy

Tags: python, tweepy

I am creating an auto-DM bot using tweepy. I want to add emojis to the text. Is it possible? I have tried adding `''`
and `:heartpulse::heart_eyes_cat:` without luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding :heartpulse::heart_eyes_cat: like this doesn't help.

Since emoticons are just special characters, all you have to do is use the right encoding to add them in the text. All you need to display is the font that support them.

U+1F601 is 16 bit unicode. In this U+1F601 is unicode representation of emoticon character.

[image]

For more info on the unicode and utf representation of emoticons refer to the following link.
https://apps.timwhitlock.info/emoji/tables/unicode

Comment: This was very helpful but Could you please add a code example. I have tried posting via tweepy api the following but the literal code just appears there: "hello U+1F923"

Comment: @ibexy I have answered you on the question you have posted. The trick is explained there.

Answer (score 1):

To complement @kharteek answer to use the Unicode code points to add the emojis to the text, for example  is `U+1F680` according to unicode.org.
So in python3 you can do something like:

```
rocket = '\U0001F680'
print(rocket)
```

Answer (score 0):

actually, a much simple thing is to just add the emoji to the text like this:

```
tweet_test = 'this is emoji '
api.update_status(status=tweet)
```